# How to record both sides of a call made with a SIP client

Tags: webrtc, sip

I am trying to record a call in chrome that is done with [sipML5](http://www.doubango.org/sipml5/).

So basically the call handling is working fine and calls go through perfectly and both parties can hear each other perfectly.

The problem comes when I want to record the call.
So I just did the bare minimum to get a recording.

```
chunks = [];
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
    .then(stream => {
        rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        rec.ondataavailable = e => {
            chunks.push(e.data);
        }
    })
    .catch(e=>console.log(e));
```

Then start a call with someone, it rings, they answer,
then I do `rec.start();` in the console. Then after 5 seconds of conversation I end the call and do `rec.stop();` in the console.

Then I do:

```
blob = new Blob(chunks,{type:'audio/ogg'});
$('.audio-remote', document).attr('src',URL.createObjectURL(blob))
```

to create the blob and provide the audio element with the src it needs.

That audio element then immediately starts playing back the audio and it is only the browser side of the conversation. Nothing is heard from the side of the cellphone. So only my voice through my mic is recorded.

Now I am not an expert on everything WebRTC, but it looks like getUserMedia provides you with a stream of only your devices and input and has nothing to do with the fact that your having a sip induced call with another party. Then obviously this is what sipML5 must do on the inside is take my input and send it through to the sip provider we use which translates it into the phone call. And the voice coming from the phone call is just presented to me through that audio element.

So I want to know if there is way to capture this conversation as is?
To capture both my input and the voice data from the sip client as one conversation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recording conversations without permission is illegal in most of the world.
Are you alerting your victim of the recording?

Comment: That is a good observation, and yes our clients will inform the people they call.

And on another note I just found this after looking some more, cannot believe I did not find this the first time as I tried all different kinds of searches and this one looks like it must've hit once, but alas.[ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827103/record-mic-and-audio-from-sip-call-using-sip-js?rq=1)